# Automated process unable to do chatter post

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Error:Insufficient Privileges: The Connect API is not enabled for this user type.1246

Leads are pushed from external system and duplicate rule fires.

Trigger runs in automated process context to check duplicate. After that chatter post is made.
Seems like automated process does not have chatter post access.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems with the user license type, it does not support chatter feature.
Can you please try it with system admin user?

Comment: Yes this was my prime concern but I cross that too. Users license type is salesforce and Chatter is enabled.

Comment: Trigger runs in automated process context to check duplicate. After that chatter post is made.  Can you please explain this part ?

Comment: When Duplicate record is found. I link it to the existing lead. Thats happening in automated process context. as soon as it is linked I do a chatter post on lead.